# AsyncTask Syntax Errors

Tags: java, android, http, android-asynctask

I have no idea what I've done wrong - but I'm having several issues with compiling the following code after combining the source code from two different files I had and implementing AsyncTask. Any suggestions as to what could be causing these issues (as a learning experience) and if it's not too complicated a way to resolve them is appreciated.

(Thanks in advance!)

PROBLEMS:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

```
The nested type AddEditCountry cannot hide an enclosing type    AddEditCountry.java /Game Demo/src/com/nfc/gamedemo line 159    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /Game Demo/src/com/nfc/gamedemo line 153    Java Problem
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable  AddEditCountry.java /Game Demo/src/com/nfc/gamedemo line 153    Java Problem
```

P.S.

I've been able to come up with the source code below with the help of several users however I'm still having several problems (listed below) and the string of data:  http://gamedemo.hostzi.com/apply.cgi?submit_button=Wireless_MAC&change_action=&action=Apply&wl_macmode=allow&wl_maclist=32&wait_time=3&wl_mac_filter=1&start=&wl_macmode1=allow&m0=00%3A1E%3A33%3AFE%3A0D%3A38&m16=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m1=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m17=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m2=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m18=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m3=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m19=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m4=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m20=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m5=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m21=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m6=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m22=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m7=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m23=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m8=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m24=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m9=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m25=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m10=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m26=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m11=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m27=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m12=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m28=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m13=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m29=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m14=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m30=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m15=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&m31=00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00&end=

...never appears to hit the server (I'm checking the logs - no changes when clicking submit in the app which is supposed to send the string above - and if I paste that URL in a browser it works successfully)

Also - the reason it never appears on the server might be being caused by the fact I have to hit space before I can click submit because the text box is required before clicking submit - I think I may need to eliminate the text box entirely (I don't need it at all - I just want to send the predefined string of data) but Im not sure I know how to do so without butchering the source code.

JAVA:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.Visibility;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DeviceConfig extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText value;
    private Button btn;
    private ProgressBar pb;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.deviceconfig);
        value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(value.getText().toString().length()<1){

                // out of range
                Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());      
            }


    } 

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postData(params[0]);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
            pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.1/apply.cgi");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I have modified your code try this http://pastebin.com/w96zfcPe, you haven't clarified me when do you want to execute your asyncTask

Comment: I ran the source code provided - almost perfect! Still have a few errors in the problem log and the string of data never hits the server - but I feel like we're getting VERY close to having it working!

Answer (score 4):

`new MyAsyncTask().execute`  // this is wrong

execute() is method

call like this

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute("");
```

You code have lot of Errors. You have placed code out side of outside of onCreate

Comment: @FLDev2013 : you are still getting any issue?

Comment: Yes Ive updated my source above to reflect the current issues

Comment: Wait - I didnt see your new source via pastebin - let me try - just a moment

Comment: Updated my notes / problems above

Answer (score 1):

Look at the line before new MyAsyncTask :

```
    }{
     new MyAsyncTask().execute
```

this is messing up all your code.
Indent properly in your IDE ((CTRL-A I) in eclipse for instance). This will make such problems more readable.

In java :

```
* all statements (java instructions) must be inside methods.
* all methods inside classes.
```

That's a good start. ;)

Comment: [current problems listed above]

Comment: Still having issues... any suggestions?

Comment: Build your program slowly, little block by little blocks, getting sure every 5 lines are ok... It looks like you did a huge copy paste and you can't handle it as too many things change at a single time and you don't seem very familiar with java language. Go slowly, be careful of every detail.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you create AddEditCountry class on the button click! :) Refactoring will solve your problems.

Comment: Is this something that can be done from the refactoring menu - or did you mean manually refactoring by picking through the code (if its the latter - thats what Im doing now! Trying to figure out what went wrong piece by piece!) : )